# (Vue3) [Vue warn]: Property "..." was accessed during render but is not defined on instance. at <App> error when Class binding

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="gameboard">
      <div class="title">Game Board</div>
      <div class="main">
        <div
          v-for="item in boardFields"
          :key="item.number"
          :class="{ notclicked: !isclicked, clicked: isclicked }"
          @click="toggleClick(item)"
        >
          {{ item.number }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {},

  data() {
    return {
      boardFields: [],
    };
  },

  methods: {
    toggleClick(item) {
      item.isclicked = !item.isclicked;
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.boardFields = [...Array(49)].map((_, i) => ({
      number: i + 1,
      isclicked: false,
    }));
  },
};
</script>

<style>

.notclicked {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0.3rem;
  width: calc(40.4rem / 7);
  height: calc(40.4rem / 7);
  border-radius: 0.8rem;
}

.clicked {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0.3rem;
  width: calc(40.4rem / 7);
  height: calc(40.4rem / 7);
  border-radius: 0.8rem;
}

</style>
```

I want to change the class of each 'boardFields object' div through a click event by class binding to the 'isclicked' boolean in each object but I get this error message:

> [Vue warn]: Property "isclicked" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.
> at

Does it have something to do with the fact that the objects are created in `mounted()`? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is in the `class-binding`:

```
:class="{ notclicked: !item.isclicked, clicked: item.isclicked }"
```

Comment: Can you explain why this is the case?

Comment: @Lesbaa ``isclicked`` is not defined in ``data``, but it's an attribute in each ``item``, so the way OP was accessing it was not valid.

Comment: Sorry @majed-badawi, I meant can you explain why this is not the case in your answer? Just to make it clearer for whomsoever visits next.

Answer (score 1):

the parameters passed in by the a method have no meaning for the effect you want to achieve.i don't know whether you want to change the whole array after clicking or a single one. my example i give is to change the entire array, changeing the current one is almost the same , just adding a pointer to the loop where it traverses

```js
data() {
  return {
isclicked: false,
  }
},
methods: {
  toggleClick(item) {
this.isclicked = !this.isclicked;
  },
},
```

```html
<div
  v-for="item in 10"
  :class="{ notclicked: !isclicked, clicked: isclicked }"
  @click="toggleClick()"
>
  {{ item }}
</div>
```